# How do you jump in anodyne?

Tags: anodyne

I have been playing Anodyne for a while and have not had to jump. But, I have reached a point where I need to jump over a few "sink holes".

I have checked the config (playing with a keyboard) and set the mapping for `???` to `x`. I have also tried changing it to `a`, but pressing `a` or `c` (mapped to attack) does not allow me to jump at all.

Has anyone seen this issue? How do you jump in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you cannot just jump in the game. Certain things needs to be done.

Hence the spoiler ;)

> You need to take Miao the cat to the orange fish guy with the box and rescue Icky the cat. Take the box to the merchant to buy the biking shoes. Take the biking shoes to the girl with the motorcycle and she will give you her old pair of shoes, which jump.

Comment: You might want to add to the answer, that once have unlocked the [Jump Shoes](http://anodyne.wikia.com/wiki/Jump_Shoes), you jump with the `x` key by default.